# How to declare/set a static variable inside a method

Tags: c#, methods, static, get, set

I cannot get/set a static variable inside a method. How can I do it?

```
    public class LoginDialog
{
    // class members

    private static string _user=""  ;

    public  void RunDialog()
    {

        _user = "Peter";

    }

    public static string _User { get; set; }

}
```

After reading the answers I edit my code and I cant still get the static variable _user. What I am doing wrong?

```
    public class LoginDialog
{   
    private static string _user;  

    public void RunDialog()
    {
       LoginDialog._user = "Peter";
    }
    public static string _User { get {return _user;}  }
}
```

When I declare like that everything works fine, but rather I would like to declare inside the method.

```
 private static string _user="Peter";
```

Comment: If you are expecting to set `_user` and access it through `_User` then that won't work as `_User` is currently an auto-property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting a private static field, and then presumably reading the public static property elsewhere.  In your code, the public static property is completely independent of the private static field.

Try this:

```
public class LoginDialog 
{ 
    // class members
    public  void RunDialog() 
    {
        _User = "Peter";
    }

    public static string _User { get; private set; } 
}
```

The property `_User` creates its own invisible private backing field, which is why it is entirely separate from the private `_user` field you declared elsewhere.

(Style guidelines dictate the name `User` for the public static property, but that's just a guideline.)

Here's another approach, for earlier versions of C# that do not support automatic properties, and without the underscore in the public property name:

```
public class LoginDialog 
{
    private static string _user;

    // class members
    public  void RunDialog() 
    {
        _user = "Peter";
    }

    public static string User { get { return _user; } } 
}
```

Comment: +1 Most likely has to be the problem even though the OP doesn't state how he is trying to "get" the static value.

Comment: where is the variable static declaration??? (BTW works!!)

why in my example does not work?

Comment: @kmxillo The static variable declaration is via a feature called "Auto Implemented Properties", or "Auto Properties" that have the syntax `PropName { get; set; }` where neither the get or set have content.  You access the property and the compiler makes a backing field for it automagically, you never see or are able to access this field in C#. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Comment: @phoog: How can I set the private static variable inside the class, no from an external one? I will like to get from external class, no set.

Comment: @kmxillo both examples in this answer have a private field that can only be set within the declaring class.

Comment: @phoog Ok, I can get the private static value from the declaring class. But my solution needs from another class retrieve that variable, and it is not working as I expect. It is not retreived. 

I am doing the following in another class: string s =  LoginDialog.User; (calling the get method from LoginDialog)

Comment: @kmxillo which of the two examples in this answer are you using?